# Printing in landscape from a Windows Forms WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, printing, webbrowser-control, landscape

I have a WebBrowser control in a Windows Forms Host in a WPF application. I know that in order to print it's contents, I use simply `WebBrowser.Print()`, however, how can I tell the printer to print the contents in landscape rather than a portrait orientation? I've been searching the Internet on this and oddly enough, it seems to be actually something that is a bit hard to do -- is this really the case? It seems odd to me that it wouldn't be easily implementable.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

INFO: WebOCHostCSharp.exe Hosts the WebBrowser Control in C# .NET

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326217

The Print(String) method prints a document and does not display a dialog box. This method uses a Microsoft HTML (MSHTML) print template to automatically control print options such as paper size, **orientation**, and number of copies.

*Note: This project does **NOT** contain this mystery overloaded method "Print(string)", It's actually called "PrintFormatted(string)"*

Comment: Somehow, this KB article was removed, all we have now is the VB.NET cousin WebOCHostVB.exe http://support.microsoft.com//kb/311303. And you can't actually "automatically control (...) paper size". The `pageWidth` and `pageHeight` properties of the `TemplatePrinter` object are read-only. You can switch them though, by setting the `orientation` property.